# PHP Update operation showing network ERROR

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am working on a simple php crud operation for a database table. I follow one crud project available in https://codeshack.io/crud-application-php-pdo-mysql/ this url.
But for my sql database I edit the code.

The read, delete and create operations are working perfect after modifying the code for my database table. --->> But Update operation is not working when i try to update!!! I tried to find out the problem but I can't see any problem in the code.

here is my update code after modification for my table name Film where there are 14 attributes. The primary key of the table Film is Film_ID.

```
<?php
include 'functions.php';
$pdo = pdo_connect_mysql();
$msg = '';
// Check if the Film id exists, for example update.php?id=1 will get the film with the id of 1
if (isset($_GET['Film_ID'])) {
    if (!empty($_POST)) {
        // This part is similar to the create.php, but instead we update a record and not insert
        $Film_ID = isset($_POST['Film_ID']) ? $_POST['Film_ID'] : NULL;
        $LanguageID = isset($_POST['LanguageID']) ? $_POST['LanguageID'] : '';
        $RegionID = isset($_POST['RegionID']) ? $_POST['RegionID'] : '';
        $Title = isset($_POST['Title']) ? $_POST['Title'] : '';
        $Description = isset($_POST['Description']) ? $_POST['Description'] : '';

        $Release_Year = isset($_POST['Release_Year']) ? $_POST['Release_Year'] : '';
        $Rental_Duration = isset($_POST['Rental_Duration']) ? $_POST['Rental_Duration'] : '';
        $Rental_Rate = isset($_POST['Rental_Rate']) ? $_POST['Rental_Rate'] : '';

        $Length = isset($_POST['Length']) ? $_POST['Length'] : '';
        $Replacement_Cost = isset($_POST['Replacement_Cost']) ? $_POST['Replacement_Cost'] : '';
        $Rating = isset($_POST['Rating']) ? $_POST['Rating'] : '';

        $Special_Features = isset($_POST['Special_Features']) ? $_POST['Special_Features'] : '';
        $FullText_Var = isset($_POST['FullText_Var']) ? $_POST['FullText_Var'] : '';

        $Last_Update = isset($_POST['Last_Update']) ? $_POST['Last_Update'] : date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        // Update the record
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE Film 
                        SET Film_ID = ?, LanguageID = ?, 
                            RegionID = ?, Title = ?, 
                            Description = ?, Release_Year = ?, 
                            Rental_Duration = ?, Rental_Rate = ?, 
                            Length = ?, Replacement_Cost = ?, 
                            Rating = ?, Special_Features = ?,
                            FullText_Var = ?, Last_Update = ? 
                        WHERE id = ?');

        $stmt->execute([$Film_ID, $LanguageID, 
                        $RegionID, $Title, 
                        $Description, $Release_Year, 
                        $Rental_Duration, $Rental_Rate,
                        $Length, $Replacement_Cost, 
                        $Rating,$Special_Features, 
                        $FullText_Var, $Last_Update, 
                        $_GET['Film_ID']]);
        $msg = 'Updated Successfully!';
    }
    // Get the films from the Film table
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM Film WHERE Film_ID = ?');
    $stmt->execute([$_GET['Film_ID']]);
    $films = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if (!$films) {
        exit('Film doesn\'t exist with that ID!');
    }
} else {
    exit('No ID specified!');
}
?>

<?=template_header('Read')?>

<div class="content update">
    <h2>Update Films #<?=$films['Film_ID']?></h2>
    <form action="update.php?Film_ID=<?=$films['Film_ID']?>" method="post">
        <label for="Film_ID">FilmID</label>
        <input type="text" name="Film_ID" placeholder="1" value="<?=$films['Film_ID']?>" id="Film_ID">

        <label for="LanguageID">LanguageID</label>
        <input type="text" name="LanguageID" placeholder="1" value="<?=$films['LanguageID']?>" id="LanguageID">

        <label for="RegionID">RegionID</label>
        <input type="text" name="RegionID" placeholder="1" value="<?=$films['RegionID']?>" id="RegionID">

    
        <label for="Title">Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="Title" placeholder="Title" value="<?=$films['Title']?>" id="Title">
        <label for="Description">Description</label>
        <input type="text" name="Description" placeholder="Description" value="<?=$films['Description']?>" id="Description">

        <label for="Release_Year">Release_Year</label>
        <input type="text" name="Release_Year" placeholder="Release_Year" value="<?=$films['Release_Year']?>" id="Release_Year">
        <label for="Rental_Duration">Rental_Duration</label>
        <input type="text" name="Rental_Duration" placeholder="Rental_Duration" value="<?=$films['Rental_Duration']?>" id="Rental_Duration">

        <label for="Rental_Rate">Rental_Rate</label>
        <input type="text" name="Rental_Rate" placeholder="Rental_Rate" value="<?=$films['Rental_Rate']?>" id="Rental_Rate">
        <label for="Length">Length</label>
        <input type="text" name="Length" placeholder="Length" value="<?=$films['Length']?>" id="Length">

        <label for="Replacement_Cost">Replacement_Cost</label>
        <input type="text" name="Replacement_Cost" placeholder="Replacement_Cost" value="<?=$films['Replacement_Cost']?>" id="Replacement_Cost">
        <label for="Rating">Rating</label>
        <input type="text" name="Rating" placeholder="Rating" value="<?=$films['Rating']?>" id="Rating">

        <label for="Special_Features">Special_Features</label>
        <input type="text" name="Special_Features" placeholder="Special_Features" value="<?=$films['Special_Features']?>" id="Special_Features">
        <label for="FullText_Var">FullText_Var</label>
        <input type="text" name="FullText_Var" placeholder="FullText_Var" value="<?=$films['FullText_Var']?>" id="FullText_Var">
       
        <label for="Last_Update">Last_Update</label>
        <input type="datetime-local" name="Last_Update" value="<?=date('Y-m-d\TH:i', strtotime($films['Last_Update']))?>" id="Last_Update">
        <input type="submit" value="Update">
    </form>
    <?php if ($msg): ?>
    <p><?=$msg?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>

<?=template_footer()?>
```

Comment: We'd like to help you, but "Not working" isn't an error message or problem statement. We can't fix "not working" in code, any more than a mechanic can fix a car that is "not working", without any other information about the problem. How is it not working? What exactly happens when you run the code? What did you expect to happen instead? Please provide details of error messages, unexpected behaviour etc. that you've obtained from your attempts to debug it.

Comment: Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example. 
Even if you are developing on a server configured as LIVE you will now see any errors. 
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: @ADyson Hi thank you for your answer. Actually, when I click update the sreen become white and noting show. I checked inspect element and find out in network section that maybe there is a connection problem. but all other commands are working.

Comment: In addition to what RiggsFolly suggested, please also add the necessary code to enable [PDO error handling](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php). It's not surprising that you don't find errors if you don't enable errors. Enabling the error reporting should be the first minimum setup step when developing your code.